# How to load a file as UTF-32 in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website where I need to display some UTF-32 text files to a user. However, whenever I open the file, it seems to be in UTF-16. I couldn't find anything else on how to do this.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Not much, it's a raw text file, and I could not find much on the internet about what to try

Comment: Or, if it's being served from a server, probably it can be set via the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) ?

Comment: Write a script that converts the files to UTF-8 before sending them back to the client.

Comment: What does "open the file" mean here?